# Why is Python loop timed inside faster than loop timed outside?

Tags: python, loops, time, memory-management

I was timing my function to figure out where the high execution time is coming from and noticed that the cumulative time inside the loop is much lower than the time of the loop itself.

I use a global variable Node.sstats to store cumulative time ie. at every iteration a variable storing the total time is increased.

I simplified my code, but I don't believe it changes the problem. I time the loop (t3-t2) as well as the cumulative time inside the loop (t5-t4). The time for t3 - t2 is 10x greater than t5 - t4. Therefore, the loop time is much larger than the cumulative time of the loop contents. I also checked and the time for updating the global variable Node.ksstats (t5b-t5) is not significant compared to the total loop time (<1%). So is the looping mechanism itself the cause or does it have something to do with memory access?

Here is my code

```
t2 = time.time()
for a in range(0, d):
    t4 = time.time()
    
    t6 = time.time()
    kurt[a], moments[a] = ik.incr_kurtosis(X[:,a], moments[a])
    t7 = time.time()
      
    Node.ksstats[2] += (t7- t6)
    kurt[a] = log(kurt[a] + 1)
    summ += kurt[a]
   
    # measure the cumulative time of the loop contents         
    t5 = time.time()
    Node.ksstats[3] += (t5-t4)
    # measure cumulative time to update ksstats variable

    t5b= time.time()
    Node.ksstats[5] += (t5b-t5)

# time entire for loop
t3 = time.time()
Node.ksstats[4] += (t3 - t2)
```

**UPDATE**

I am still not sure what was going on, but I made the loop inner and outer time equate by updating a local ksstats variable inside the loop instead of the class variable, Node.ksstats

Comment: You would be better off using Pylton profiling tools https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: I am aware of profiling tools, but I still don't understand the underlying mechanism causing this

Comment: Can you try `time.monotonic()` instead of `time.time()` to see if it change anything?

Comment: this doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: Is `d` about 10 by any chance?

Comment: No d varies by dataset (number of dimensions) and is 166 in the most problematic example